# What are the de facto features used for 3D gesture recognition?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I want to develop a gesture recognition.  I'm considering using the Kinect to have 3D data, but I don't know what features are the go-to features for gesture recognition.

What are the standard features used in gesture recognition?  My intuition tells me optical flow would be useful, but I'm not sure how that would be used, to be honest.  Clearly, the features will need to be temporal, rather than just spatial.

Thanks!

Comment: Please define `feature`. If you mean optical feature as in SIFT etc, then I think you are on the wrong track.

Comment: This was kind of what I meant, although I know that the features need to be temporal, not just spatial.  That's why I asked the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware Microsoft uses joint angles as features (as in, a feature approximates the state of the system and lets you distinguish various poses).

Here is a paper by some Microsoft Research researchers:
http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~cs104/BodyPartRecognition.pdf